# Trying to retrieve post meta

Tags: php, theme-development, functions, custom-field, metabox

I have created a meta box that allows users to add an additional name/id to their post. From what I can tell it is adding the meta information correctly because when I edit a post that has a custom name/ID it shows up in the input box by default as it should.

So my issue is that I am trying to pull the custom ID/name and use it as an additional ID tag in the code. Although it is not retrieving anything. When I use the code in my theme and check the html on the page the ID is showing ID="". So for some reason it is not pulling anything. Can anyone see an issue?

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
    <?php $value = get_post_meta($post_id, 'newtheme_section_id'); ?>
    <id="<?php $value; ?>">
```

If I change get_the_ID() to the_ID() then it returns a value but it is the post ID instead of the custom id the user entered into the feild.

EDIT: I was able to figure it out by echoing the function instead of storing it in a variable, along with Mannys suggestion . Here is the updated code.

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
<id="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta($post_id, 'newtheme_section_id', true) ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you include the third argument to `get_post_meta`, a Boolean that determines whether or not it returns a single item or an array of items.  The default is false, which is an array, so set it to true:

```
  <?php $value = get_post_meta ($post_id, 'newtheme_section_id', true ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added it but unfortunately I am still having the same issue.

Comment: I was able to echo the function instead of storing it(output) in a variable. I had tried this before your suggestion and it did not work, so I am marking your post as the answer.